# How to create a timer in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, timer

I would need to create a timer that deletes the first data from the 1st database and takes the 1st data from the second database and puts it into the 1st database and then the 1st data from the 2nd database delete. Can it be constructed somehow? Thank you for the advice

```
CREATE EVENT DELLKALDAY
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 60 SECOND
STARTS '2012-11-28 19:43:00'
DO DELETE FROM kalendardays LIMIT 1;

CREATE EVENT ADDKALDAY
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 63 SECOND
STARTS '2012-11-28 19:43:00'
DO INSERT FROM kalendarfull LIMIT 1 TO kalendardays;

CREATE EVENT DELLFULLKALDAY
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 66 SECOND
STARTS '2012-11-28 19:43:00'
DO DELETE FROM kalendarfull LIMIT 1;
```

I've tried something like that but I think it's stupid and I want to point out that I'm new to MYSQL.

Comment: You need in ONE event procedure which performs all 3 actions in needed order. And while creating a procedure you must strictly follow the syntax.

Comment: Well yes but how do I put it in that one it keeps throwing me errors

Comment: Study the syntax and follow it. Do not try to imagine your own syntax - server will accept it never.

Comment: ...and what are the FULL error messages? ... please append to the question an not as a comment in this area.